# Role assumption errors with boto3, aws workdocs, and Lambda execution with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have the confirmed the following policy and trust relationships in account-b

Trust Relationship

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::account-b:assumed-role/WorkDocs_API_Developer/workdocs_session"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

And the associated policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "workdocs:GetDocumentPath",
                "workdocs:GetCurrentUser",
                "workdocs:CreateNotificationSubscription",
                "workdocs:DescribeAvailableDirectories",
                "workdocs:UpdateFolder",
                "workdocs:CheckAlias",
                "workdocs:DownloadDocumentVersion",
                "workdocs:GetResources",
                "workdocs:DescribeActivities",
                "workdocs:DescribeRootFolders",
                "workdocs:UpdateDocument",
                "workdocs:CreateFolder",
                "workdocs:GetFolder",
                "workdocs:InitiateDocumentVersionUpload",
                "workdocs:DescribeResourcePermissions",
                "workdocs:DescribeDocumentVersions",
                "workdocs:CreateLabels",
                "workdocs:DescribeGroups",
                "workdocs:DescribeNotificationSubscriptions",
                "workdocs:DescribeFolderContents",
                "workdocs:AbortDocumentVersionUpload",
                "workdocs:DescribeComments",
                "workdocs:GetDocumentVersion",
                "workdocs:AddResourcePermissions",
                "workdocs:DescribeInstances",
                "workdocs:GetDocument",
                "workdocs:DescribeUsers",
                "workdocs:CreateComment",
                "workdocs:CreateCustomMetadata",
                "workdocs:UpdateDocumentVersion",
                "workdocs:GetFolderPath"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

here is my current code:

```
import os
import sys

# this adds the parent directory of bin so we can find the  module
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
#This addes venv lib/python3.6/site-packages/ to the search path
mod_path = os.path.abspath(parent_dir+"/lib/python"+str(sys.version_info[0])+"."+str(sys.version_info[1])+"/site-packages/")
sys.path.append(mod_path)

from base64 import b64decode
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import requests

workdocs_region ='us-west-2'
services_region = 'us-east-1'
wd_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::account-b:role/WorkDocs_API_Developer'


def assume_role(wd_role_arn):
    sts = boto3.client('sts')
    creds = sts.assume_role(RoleArn=wd_role_arn,
                            RoleSessionName='workdocs_session'
                            )['Credentials']
    return creds

def get_data():
    role = assume_role(wd_role_arn) 
    client = boto3.client('workdocs',
                          aws_access_key_id=role['AccessKeyId'],
                          aws_secret_access_key=role['SecretAccessKey'],
                          aws_session_token=role['SessionToken'],
                          region_name=workdocs_region
                          )

    folder_id = os.environ['FOLDER_ID']
    doc_id = os.environ['DOC_ID']

    if not doc_id:   
        documents = client.describe_folder_contents(FolderId = folder_id)
        file = os.environ['FILE_NAME'].replace(' ','_')
        for d in documents['Documents']:
            if file in d['LatestVersionMetadata']['Name'].replace(' ','_'):
                print(d['LatestVersionMetadata']['Id'])
                doc_id = d['LatestVersionMetadata']['Id']

    doc_meta = client.get_document(
                    DocumentId=doc_id
                    )

    latest_doc = client.get_document_version(
                    DocumentId=doc_meta['Metadata']['Id'],
                    VersionId=doc_meta['Metadata']['LatestVersionMetadata']['Id'],
                    Fields='SOURCE'
                    )

    document_url = latest_doc['Metadata']['Source']['ORIGINAL']
    document_name = latest_doc['Metadata']['Name']
    r = requests.get(document_url)

    wb = load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(r.content))
    for s in wb.sheetnames:
        ws = wb[s]
        data = ws.values
        columns = next(data)[0:]
        columns = [item.lower().replace(' ', '_').strip() for item in columns]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        df['snapshot_date'] = datetime.date.today()
        if os.environ['OUT_LOCATION'] in ['Redshift', 'redshift', 'rs'] :
            redshift_load(df)
        elif os.environ['OUT_LOCATION'] in ['S3' , 's3'] :
            s3_load(df, s)

def redshift_load(df):
    rs = os.environ['REDSHIFT_INSTANCE']
    rs_port = os.environ['REDSHIFT_PORT']
    rs_db = os.environ['REDSHIFT_DB']
    rs_user = os.environ['REDSHIFT_USER']
    rs_password = boto3.client('kms', region_name=services_region).decrypt(CiphertextBlob=b64decode(os.environ['REDSHIFT_PASSWORD']))['Plaintext']
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(rs_user,rs_password.decode('utf-8'),rs,rs_port,rs_db))
    schema = os.environ['SCHEMA_NAME']
    table = os.environ['TABLE_NAME']
    df.to_sql(table, engine, schema, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi')

def s3_load(df, sheet):
    session = boto3.Session()
    creds = session.get_credentials()
    client = boto3.client('s3',
                          aws_access_key_id=creds.access_key,
                          aws_secret_access_key=creds.secret_key,
                          aws_session_token=creds.token,
                          region_name=services_region,
                          )        

    csv = df.to_csv(index=False)
    key = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d') + '/' + sheet + '.csv'
    client.put_object(Bucket=os.environ['BUCKET'], Key=key, Body=csv)


def lambda_handler(event, context) :          
    get_data()
```

can anyone tell me why I would get this error:

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (UnauthorizedResourceAccessException) when calling the GetDocument operation: Principal [arn:aws:sts::289497978546:assumed-role/WorkDocs_API_Developer/workdocs_session] is not allowed to execute [workdocs:GetDocument] on the resource"
```

I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

The lambda execution role has the following in account-a

trust policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:sts::account-b:assumed-role/WorkDocs_API_Developer/workdocs_session",
          "arn:aws:iam::account-b:role/WorkDocs_API_Developer",
          "arn:aws:sts::account-a:assumed-role/Lambda-WorkDocs/corpworkdocs_api_pull_infra"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Resource Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "workdocs:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*",
                "arn:aws:sts::account-b:assumed-role/WorkDocs_API_Developer/workdocs_session"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there something I didn't do in my code? Is there some kind of problem with the trust or resource policies?

Comment: Have you checked the output of `assume_role()` to see whether it is returning a set of credentials? The first thing that confuses me is that the Lambda execution role does not assign the Lambda function permission to call `sts.assume_role()`. That permission should be in the "resource policy", but that policy is only allocating permission to call Workdocs (which is also strange, because it appears that you are only using workdocs via the assigned role, rather than via the role assigned to the Lambda function). So, the first thing to check is whether the call to `sts.assume_role()` is working.

Comment: when I print the creds supplied in get_data to the client for workdocs there is a full set of credentials.

Comment: Turns out that whatever the ID is in the dictionary that is being returned by `d['LatestVersionMetadata']['Id']` is not the correct document ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I was using the incorrect ID the existing code was pulling Id from latest metadata.  That is not the actual document Id.  I don't know what the Id is for in that section, but it isn't document.

You have to go back to Document for the correct Id.  Here is the code:

```
import os
import sys

# this adds the parent directory of bin so we can find the  module
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir))
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
#This addes venv lib/python3.6/site-packages/ to the search path
mod_path = os.path.abspath(parent_dir+"/lib/python"+str(sys.version_info[0])+"."+str(sys.version_info[1])+"/site-packages/")
sys.path.append(mod_path)

from base64 import b64decode
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import requests

workdocs_region ='us-west-2'
services_region = 'us-east-1'
wd_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::account-b:role/WorkDocs_API_Developer'


def assume_role(wd_role_arn):
    sts = boto3.client('sts')
    creds = sts.assume_role(RoleArn=wd_role_arn,
                            RoleSessionName='workdocs_session'
                            )['Credentials']
    return creds

def get_data():
    role = assume_role(wd_role_arn) 
    client = boto3.client('workdocs',
                          aws_access_key_id=role['AccessKeyId'],
                          aws_secret_access_key=role['SecretAccessKey'],
                          aws_session_token=role['SessionToken'],
                          region_name=workdocs_region
                          )

    folder_id = os.environ['FOLDER_ID']
    doc_id = os.environ['DOC_ID']

    if not doc_id:   
        documents = client.describe_folder_contents(FolderId = folder_id)
        file = os.environ['FILE_NAME'].replace(' ','_')
        for d in documents['Documents']:
            if file in d['LatestVersionMetadata']['Name'].replace(' ','_'):
                doc_id = d['Id']

    doc_meta = client.get_document(
                    DocumentId=doc_id
                    )

    latest_doc = client.get_document_version(
                    DocumentId=doc_meta['Metadata']['Id'],
                    VersionId=doc_meta['Metadata']['LatestVersionMetadata']['Id'],
                    Fields='SOURCE'
                    )

    document_url = latest_doc['Metadata']['Source']['ORIGINAL']
    document_name = latest_doc['Metadata']['Name']
    r = requests.get(document_url)

    wb = load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(r.content))
    for s in wb.sheetnames:
        ws = wb[s]
        data = ws.values
        columns = next(data)[0:]
        columns = [item.lower().replace(' ', '_').strip() for item in columns]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        df['snapshot_date'] = datetime.date.today()
        if os.environ['OUT_LOCATION'] in ['Redshift', 'redshift', 'rs'] :
            redshift_load(df)
        elif os.environ['OUT_LOCATION'] in ['S3' , 's3'] :
            s3_load(df, s)

def redshift_load(df):
    rs = os.environ['REDSHIFT_INSTANCE']
    rs_port = os.environ['REDSHIFT_PORT']
    rs_db = os.environ['REDSHIFT_DB']
    rs_user = os.environ['REDSHIFT_USER']
    rs_password = boto3.client('kms', region_name=services_region).decrypt(CiphertextBlob=b64decode(os.environ['REDSHIFT_PASSWORD']))['Plaintext']
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(rs_user,rs_password.decode('utf-8'),rs,rs_port,rs_db))
    schema = os.environ['SCHEMA_NAME']
    table = os.environ['TABLE_NAME']
    df.to_sql(table, engine, schema, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi')

def s3_load(df, sheet):
    session = boto3.Session()
    creds = session.get_credentials()
    client = boto3.client('s3',
                          aws_access_key_id=creds.access_key,
                          aws_secret_access_key=creds.secret_key,
                          aws_session_token=creds.token,
                          region_name=services_region,
                          )        

    csv = df.to_csv(index=False)
    key = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y/%m/%d') + '/' + sheet + '.csv'
    client.put_object(Bucket=os.environ['BUCKET'], Key=key, Body=csv)


def lambda_handler(event, context) :          
    get_data()
```